# Lagrangian submanifold of Poisson manifolds

Tags: reference-request, sg.symplectic-geometry, poisson-geometry

Let $V$ be a finite dimensional vector space.
Let $\psi\in \Lambda^2V$ be a (possibly degenerate)  $2$-vector. Then $\psi$ defines a map $V^*\rightarrow V$. Let $U\subset V$ denote the image of this map. Then $\psi$ induces a symplectic form $\sigma$ on $U$. A subspace $Z\subset V$ is Lagrangian with respect to $\psi$ if $Z$ is a Lagrangian subspace of $(U,\sigma)$ in the usual symplectic sense.

Now let $M$ be a Poisson manifold; i.e., it is a manifold equipped with a global $2$-vector $\psi\in H^0(M, \Lambda^2 TM)$, satisfying an appropriate integrability condition. Let us introduce the following definition:

Definition: A submanifold $N\subset M$ is Lagrangian if $T_n(N)$ is a Lagrangian subspace of $T_n(M)$ for all $n\in N$.

Question: Is this a reasonable definition? Is it equivalent to requiring that the intersection of $N$ with every symplectic leaf of $M$ is Lagrangian in that symplectic leaf?

Note that the above definition appears as Definition 2.5 in an [article](https://arxiv.org/pdf/alg-geom/9507017.pdf) of Donagi and Markman. But they work under the assumption that the rank of the Poisson structure is constant. Basically, I am wondering if it is OK to drop this assumption. A reference would be appreciated.

Comment: Since a Lagrangian subspace of a symplectic space has dimension half the dimension of the whole space, asking the Lagrangian condition in a non constant rank setting would give you a Lagrangian generalized distribution with non constant rank. This is why usually you use this condition only in a constant rank setting. In the non regular Poisson case the concept of coisotropic subspace is more frequently used.